# Wordpress Popup language switcher

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, popup, elementor

I want make wordpress pop up language switcher.
If any user visit site he needs to select his language first.
I am also make a popup with elementor and gtranslate but it is not working.
How can i make this popup?

Answer (score 1):

Both Elementor and Gtranslate have the popup function working in many cases for me, check your javascript (browser console) and see if there are any issues because that is the only reason why a popup would not work (from both these providers).